# trouble with mysql pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm having trouble creating a pivot table in MySQL using the following tables:

```
Teams
-------------
id | name
1  | teamA

Processes
-------------
id | name
1  | processA
2  | processB

ProcessDetails
---------------
id | processId | keyName
 1 |     1     |  shape
 2 |     1     |  vegetable
 3 |     1     |  fruit
 4 |     2     |  animal

TeamProcesses
-----------------
id | teamId | processId
 5 |   1    |    1
 6 |   1    |    2

TeamProcessDetails
--------------------
id | teamProcessId | proccessDetailsId | value
 1 |       5       |         1         | circle
 2 |       5       |         2         | carrot
 3 |       5       |         3         | apple
 4 |       6       |         4         | dog
```

The pivot table I'm trying to produce is this one:

```
Pivot Table
------------
teamId | processId |  shape  | vegetable |  fruit  | animal
   1   |     1     |  circle |  carrot   |  apple  |  NULL
   1   |     2     |  NULL   |   NULL    |   NULL  |  dog
```

It should be noted that the number of keys is dynamic so I think I need to use the prepared statement method. Also, the processes don't have the same keys so they should only have a value for a key that belongs to that process.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on your tables and provide some sample data for each table? It would be easier o answer with some specifics.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for taking the time to look at my post. I've updated the tables with some sample data. Hopefully that helps clarify some things. If you know a better way to construct the pivot table then that would also be ok. I basically need all the key values pairs for each process that belongs to a team. I thought of the NULLs because I didn't know what to do in the case where the keys weren't the same. I could also change the table structure if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to pivot dynamic or unknown value, I would always suggest that you start with a static or hard-coded version of the query first, then convert it to dynamic SQL.

MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT function so you will need to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result.  The static version of the code will be similar to the following:

```
select t.id teamid, 
  t.name teamname, 
  p.id processid, 
  p.name processname,
  max(case when pd.keyname = 'shape' then tpd.value end) shape,
  max(case when pd.keyname = 'vegetable' then tpd.value end) vegetable,
  max(case when pd.keyname = 'fruit' then tpd.value end) fruit,
  max(case when pd.keyname = 'animal' then tpd.value end) animal
from teams t
inner join teamprocesses tp
  on t.id = tp.teamid
inner join TeamProcessDetails tpd
  on tp.id = tpd.teamProcessId
inner join processes p
  on tp.processid = p.id
inner join processdetails pd
  on p.id = pd.processid
  and tpd.processDetailsid = pd.id
group by t.id, t.name, p.id, p.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8535e/4).

Now if you are going to have an unknown number of `keynames` that you want to convert into columns, then you will need to use a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) to generate dynamic SQL.  The code will be similar to:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when pd.keyname = ''',
      keyname,
      ''' then tpd.value end) AS ',
      replace(keyname, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from ProcessDetails;

SET @sql 
    = CONCAT('SELECT t.id teamid, 
                t.name teamname, 
                p.id processid, 
                p.name processname, ', @sql, ' 
              from teams t
              inner join teamprocesses tp
                on t.id = tp.teamid
              inner join TeamProcessDetails tpd
                on tp.id = tpd.teamProcessId
              inner join processes p
                on tp.processid = p.id
              inner join processdetails pd
                on p.id = pd.processid
                and tpd.processDetailsid = pd.id
              group by t.id, t.name, p.id, p.name;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8535e/3).

One thing to keep in mind the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to create the string of columns has a default max length of 1024, so if you are going to have a lot of characters in this string you might have to alter the session value for the `group_concat_max_len`.

This query will give a result:

```
| TEAMID | TEAMNAME | PROCESSID | PROCESSNAME |  SHAPE | VEGETABLE |  FRUIT | ANIMAL |
|      1 |    teamA |         1 |    processA | circle |    carrot |  apple | (null) |
|      1 |    teamA |         2 |    processB | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    dog |
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this solves my problem.
Just one question, what does the MAX on each case do?

Comment: Typically when you pivot data, you use an aggregate function for the results return a single row for the items.

Comment: How could I modify this so that only the keyNames that are assigned to those processes are pulled and not all the keyNames in processDetails table.

Comment: @hebime My suggestion would be to Ask a new question with the new details and requirements.

Comment: Thanks, here is the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058595/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns