# Pivot table with dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm having trouble creating a pivot table in MySQL using the following tables:

```
Teams
-------------
id | name
1  | teamA
2  | teamB

Processes
-------------
id | name
1  | processA
2  | processB
3  | processC

ProcessDetails
---------------
id | processId | keyName
 1 |     1     |  shape
 2 |     1     |  vegetable
 3 |     1     |  fruit
 4 |     2     |  animal
 5 |     3     |  dessert

TeamProcesses
-----------------
id | teamId | processId
 5 |   1    |    1
 6 |   1    |    2
 7 |   2    |    3

TeamProcessDetails
--------------------
id | teamProcessId | proccessDetailsId | value
 1 |       5       |         1         | circle
 2 |       5       |         2         | carrot
 3 |       5       |         3         | apple
 4 |       6       |         4         | dog
 5 |       7       |         5         | chocolate
```

The pivot table I am trying to produce should only contain the process details for a given team.

Example

For Team A:

```
Pivot Table
------------
teamId | processId |  shape  | vegetable |  fruit  | animal
   1   |     1     |  circle |  carrot   |  apple  |  NULL
   1   |     2     |  NULL   |   NULL    |   NULL  |  dog
```

For Team B:

```
teamId | processId | dessert
   2   |     3     | chocolate
```

Thanks!

Comment: How dynamic should it be? Do you know at design time how many columns there will be and their titles?  Also, please post your own best attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this was a followup question from another I posted a while ago. @bluefeet had helped me out before.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729532/trouble-with-mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the query from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729532/trouble-with-mysql-pivot-table) you should be able to alter the code to add a WHERE clause that will filter the data for each team:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
set @team = 'teamA';

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when pd.keyname = ''',
      keyname,
      ''' then tpd.value end) AS ',
      replace(keyname, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from ProcessDetails
where processId in (select tp.processId
                    from teams t
                    inner join teamprocesses tp
                      on t.id = tp.teamid
                    where t.name = @team);

SET @sql 
    = CONCAT('SELECT t.id teamid, 
                t.name teamname, 
                p.id processid, ', @sql, ' 
              from teams t
              inner join teamprocesses tp
                on t.id = tp.teamid
              inner join TeamProcessDetails tpd
                on tp.id = tpd.teamProcessId
              inner join processes p
                on tp.processid = p.id
              inner join processdetails pd
                on p.id = pd.processid
                and tpd.processDetailsid = pd.id
              where t.name = ''', @team, ''' 
              group by t.id, t.name, p.id, p.name;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d91b/7)

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I couldn't get it to work because of the subquery.