# Dynamic Pivot Table MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table in a database that records student marks like so:

```
| id     | criteriaid   |  mark     | studentid     |
| 1      | 5            |  62       | 5             |
| 2      | 6            |  54       | 5             |
| 3      | 7            |  48       | 5             |
```

This then links to a Criteria table like so:

```
| id     | title        |
| 5      | Presentation |
| 6      | Communication|
| 7      | Research     |
```

And a student table like so:

```
| id     |firstname     | lastname       |
| 10     |Joe           | Bloggs         |
```

While I have no issue in joining the tables together, which may look like this:

```
| id | firstname | lastname  |  criteria     | mark     |
| 10 | Joe       | Bloggs    |  Presentation | 62       |
| 10 | Joe       | Bloggs    |  Communication| 54       |
| 10 | Joe       | Bloggs    |  Research     | 48       |
```

I have been experimenting with pivot table tutorials but cannot get the result I want.. which I believe is a dynamic pivot table. (the criteria needs to be dynamic). This is what I want:

```
| id | firstname | lastname  |  Presentation | Communication | Research  |
| 10 | Joe       | Bloggs    |       62      |      54       |     48    |
```

At the moment I am trying to do this hard-coded as advised here [trouble with mysql pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729532/trouble-with-mysql-pivot-table?rq=1)

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, m.mark,
  max(case when c.title = 'Attitude' then m.mark end) attitude,
  max(case when c.title = 'Acting' then m.mark end) acting,
  max(case when c.title = 'Presentation' then m.mark end) presentation,
  max(case when c.title = 'Voice' then m.mark end) voice
from marks m
LEFT JOIN criteria c ON m.criteriaid = c.id
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = m.studentid
```

This is now working well, however I'm after a dynamic solution. I'll continue trying - if anyone can help it will be still appreciated.

I am now up to here

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when c.title = ''',
          title,
          ''' then m.mark end) AS ',
          replace(title, ' ', '')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    from criteria;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname,
    ', @sql,'
    from marks m
    LEFT JOIN criteria c ON m.criteriaid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = m.studentid
    group by s.id;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This may work however not working in PHPMyAdmin... looking for a solution!

Comment: Please show us some examples of what you've tried so far. Otherwise it looks like you want someone here to do your job/homework. And not sure what you mean by 'dynamic' - a query gets run against the current data, whether natively in MySQL or via a PHP or other calling app. Good luck.

Comment: I see you've tagged this with PHP. Although you can write a sproc in MySQL that will assemble some prepared statements dynamically, it's *far* simpler to return an ordered array and handle the display logic at the application level (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Comment: Thats not a good ideia to do it on a SQL Query... its better do it on code. If you need it dynamic....

Comment: My answer is basically the same as yours. You have an unwanted comma before the FROM MARKS clause

Comment: Thank you, yes I just spotted this and it has got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the working result, however does not work in PHP. Have decided to use the hard coded option along with PHP to build the SQL string.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when c.title = ''',
          title,
          ''' then m.mark end) AS ',
          replace(title, ' ', '')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    from criteria;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname,
    ', @sql,'
    from marks m
    LEFT JOIN criteria c ON m.criteriaid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = m.studentid
    group by s.id;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see how you could make an sql table that will have different columns depending on the data in your table but you can get some of what you want.

You could use a query such as:

```
SELECT studentid,
   MAX(CASE WHEN criteriaid=5 THEN mark END) AS Presentation,
   MAX(CASE WHEN criteriaid=6 THEN mark END) AS Communication,
   MAX(CASE WHEN criteriaid=7 THEN mark END) AS Research
FROM marks
GROUP BY studentid
```

That doesn't answer your question - but it does most of the work in SQL rather than in php. You might be able to construct the SQL statement in PHP based on the criteria in the table.